# Equation to 2d points

Tags: c#

So I got this equation:

```
x^2 + y^2 = 16
```

Which most of you will know that is how you would make a circle in a graph, but how can i transform that to 2d grid like a double for loop.

What I tried:

```
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
                if (Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2) == 16) {
                   // place dot at x,y
                }
            }
        }
```

The result of this code was two dots placed in the grid, not a the expected answer which should have been a circle

Comment: I see that you have accepted an answer, so maybe improving this question isn't a top priority. Your question would be better received if you edited it to clarify what you mean by "horrible failed". In particular, how is the result of your code difference than the result you were expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a coordinate transformation sothat the object you have can be parameterized. In this case, polar coordinates ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)).

Let your object be described by all points [image] for which the equation

[image]

holds. All circle equations of the form [image] can be be paramaterized with polar coordinates, i.e. every point can be expressed as a pair of radius and angle [image]. The transformation formula is as follows:

[image]

(This has its roots in triangles, see wikipedia).
In your case `r` is constant with `r = 4`. The angle iterates all the way from `0°` to `360°`, or in radians `0` to `2π`. In pseudo-code you can draw it as

```
const double r = 4.0;
for (double angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle += 0.5) {
    //Convert polar coordinates to cartesian (x,y) coordinates
    double x = r * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
    double y = r * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
    //Put a dot at (x,y).. 
}
```

The factor `π/180` is the conversion factor from degrees to radians.